# TYPO3 what files are holding the extension informations

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

what and were is the file which holds the TYPO3 extension information? for example if an extension is activated or deactivated - and or what configurations are used or not used by the extension.

Comment: Loaded extensions could be found in typo3conf/PackageStzates.php or in the backend model «Extensions». Configuration (typoscript) can be found in backend model «Template». Which configuration you are looking for?

Comment: im looking for everything extension related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Information about installed extensions is in `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`. If the extension has configuration editable via the Extension manager, this configuration is saved in `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php`. But typically extensions contain their default configuration inside the extensions's `Configuration/TypoScript` directory. It is included as is and later can be modified by other extensions or in the main setup and stored in the database.